# iTerm now showing cursor when pressing Shift + arrow key

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, iterm2, iterm

As you can see in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlMs5.png), iTerm is adding a kind of overlay cursor (plus this paper icon) above the terminal windows when I press Shift + any arrow key. It seems to be a text selection tool or something similar.

Since I have mapped Shift + left and Shift + right arrow in tmux to switch windows, I would like to deactivate this function of iTerm, but couldn't find anything in the settings. In earlier versions this did not appear. Currently I'm using Build 3.4.20200723-nightly.

Thanks for your help!